No simple groups of order of order 4095, 4389, 5313 or 6669 using normalizers
I am working on problem 6.2.10 from Dummit and Foote. It asked us to prove there are no simple groups of order 4095, 4389, 5313 or 6669 using the method it calls “Playing $p$-subgroups off against each other”. The method involves looking at distinct pairs of primes $p$ and $q$, $p< q$, such that $p \not\mid (q-1)$ yet $p\mid |{N_G(Q)}| $ where $Q$ is a sylow $q$-subgroup, and then looking at the order of the normalizer of a $p$ subgroup of $Q$ in $G$.
For 4095, 5313, and 6669 I am unable to find these pairs and for 4389 I found that $q=11$, $p=3$ works, but there are too many options for $n_3$ to get at a contradiction.
(Note: we can not use Feit-Thompson or Burnside N/C theorem)
Any help or hints will be appreciated.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feit%E2%80%93Thompson_theorem
